# Changing the default login route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I created an authentication form using the Laravel / Auth package.

How to change Laravel default login route as shown below.

`www.example.com/login` =>  `www.example.com/custom-login-route`

Comment: You can add your own login routes instead of using the defaults. but keep in mind that you get redirected after successful login. Maybe its better to redirect to /login if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two new routes and remove the login route like so:

web.php

```
// show form route
Route::get('new-login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
// post credential to the login method
Route::post('new-login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('new-login');
// remove default login route
Auth::route(['login' => false]);
```

Now in your login.blade you must change the form action to point your new-login route:

auth/login.blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('new-login') }}">
```

Comment: How to change the autoredirect if user try to access a protected page?